How to get the result Array from the FILTER function?
Phpspreadsheet 2.0 question here.
I've got an xlsx spreadsheet where a range of cells is filled with output from the FILTER function.
In the sheet, a cell range starting at $H$3 is filled via the expression "=_xlfn._xlws.SORT(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER($D$3:$G$11,$D$3:$D$11=$H$6,""))"
How can I calculate all the cell values that are affected by the FILTER expression?
I tried calculating the H3 value by running $spreadsheet->getSheet(1)->getCell('H3')->getCalculatedValue(). It returned the correct value.
But $spreadsheet->getSheet(1)->getCell('H4')->getCalculatedValue() returns null.
